# How to avoid decimal numbers in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs

How to avoid decimal number in angular js?

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
  <label class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 pad-top5 pad-lft-no">Mins <span class="error">*</span></label>
  <input positive  type="number" class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 cls_input_inherit numberinput" min="0" ng-maxlength="3" id="age_min" name="age_min" ng-model="attributes.age_min" step="1" required/>
  <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.required" class="error">{{formValidation.required}}</label>                                                           
  <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive &&  attributesForm2.age_min.$error.maxlength" class="error"> {{formValidation.monthMaxChar}} </label>
  <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.maxlength && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.min" class="error">{{formValidation.minMax}}</label>
  <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.maxlength && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.number" class="error">{{formValidation.errorNumber}}</label>
  <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive" class="error">{{formValidation.minpositive}}</label>
  <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.required && attributesForm2.age_min.$invalid && attributesForm2.age_min.$touched" class="error">Invalid value</label>
</div>
```

It's not showing any error when user enter decimal value?Am tried step="1" and ng-pattern too,Both are not working,Is there any wrong in my code too show error message for the decimal value?How to show that error message when user enter decimal value?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern).

```
<form name="testForm">
    <input ng-model="age_min" name="age_min" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" required>
    <span ng-show="testForm.age_min.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wuU6rfnZ0OrNoguSqGwj?p=preview)